# import from a parent folder in python

Tags: python

Ive read a few posts with people struggling with this, spent a couple of hours trying various approaches but nothing has worked.

Very very simple, i just want to import code from a parent folder. The parent root folder of project has an empty **init**.py file

the structure is

```
__init__.py
services/
services/service_factory.py
etl/
etl/main.py
```

in the etl folder i am running python main.py

here is my main.py i've made it as simple as possible:

```
import sys, os
sys.path.append(os.path.abspath(os.path.join('..', 'services')))
from services.services_factory import *
print('hello world')
```

I get 'ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'services'
Can anyone explain what to change to get this to work?

Comment: Try adding the empty file `services/__init__.py` so it's recognized as a Python module.

Comment: that doesnt work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to run it as a module, your cwd should be one level higher than main.py.

```
python -m etl.main
```

Comment: that gives me Error while finding module specification for 'etls/main.py' (ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'etl/main')

Comment: there should be '.', not '/' and no '.py' extension

Comment: thanks .. that gives me No module named 'etls.services' .. ( python -m etl.main)

Comment: I can't see etls.services module in your structure.

Comment: youre right, sorry that was a typo! (on the comment)

Comment: I think when you remove line 'sys.append.path...' it should work.

Answer (score 1):

This is always very cofusing. Relative imports are relative to the module structure. To test relative imports, you need to import your module in your main file (from outside the module). Let me try to show a case that works:

```
$ python test_module.py
Hello World!
```

Or you can make it an executable module and run it with `python -m` (always from outside the module)

```
$ python -m module.etl
Hello World!
```

#### Structure

```
test_module.py
module
├── __init__.py [can be empty]
├── etl
   ├── __init__.py
   ├── __main__.py
│── services
   ├── service_factory.py
```

**`test_module.py`**

```
from module.etl import message
print(message)
```

**`service_factory.py`**

```
phrase = "Hello World"
mark = '!'
```

**`etl/__init__.py`**

```
from .__main__ import message
```

**`etl/__main__.py`**

```
from .. services.service_factory import phrase,mark

message = phrase+mark

if __name__ == "__main__":
    #this block is run when executing `python -m module.etl`

    print(message)
```

**NOTE**: if you add another file in `etl` say `etl/myscript.py` you can still execute it with `python -m module.etl.myscript` (always from outside the module)

Comment: Hey, thanks thats brilliantly formatted and really well answered and helpful! can you explain how i would then run the script in isolation? the plan here was to share modules between the etl scripts which are outside the etl folder but be able to run the etl scripts one by one

Comment: also, the file in the etl directory im running is a file not an __init__.py

Comment: Ok, I've never had the need to execute files inside a module.

Comment: pay attention to the last note :)