# Problem in getting relative import in Python

Tags: python, importerror

in my case I have folder structure as :

```
|- category 
|  |- sub-category
|    |- do_something.py
|
|- package
|  | -module.py
```

I want to import function present in module.py inside do_something.py, something like :

`from ..package.module import func_1`

How should I do this , I have tried relative path but keep getting error like :

`ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package`

Comment: hello, have a look to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66566247/import-from-a-parent-folder-in-python/66567228#66567228

Answer (score 1):

The error is because python is viewing the category and package folders as different packages.

In order for python to view them both as a sub-package of your program, you need to run your program from a parent directory of both folders. if you run do_something.py directly, then you'd get an error because python is unsure if the current package (category) has access to the package folder.
Also, remember your **init**.py files, and don't use hyphens in the folders/files names

```
|- category 
   | __init__.py
|  |- sub_category
     | __init__.py
|    |- do_something.py
|
|- package
   | __init__.py
|  | -module.py
|- FILE_TO_EXECUTE.py
```

#do_something.py

```
from ...package.module import func_1
```

#FILE_TO_EXECUTE.py

```
from category.sub_category.do_something import *
```

#SHELL

> python FILE_TO_EXECUTE.py

Since both the package and category folders are children of the current directory, python knows they are sub-packages and can do relative imports between them

Answer (score 0):

Try to use Absolute path:

```
from package.module import func_1
```

Comment: I am getting error like this when i tried your suggetion : No module named 'package_name'

Comment: @SomitraGupta hm, did you have in your code?